# Use a label to display a record from a SQL database

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I am currently trying to find a way to display records from my SQL database into a label on a form rather than a text box and have had no luck. Is there a way to do this?

Other info:
I have created the database and tables in Visual Studio 2015 and have created added them into my dataset.
I am also using Visual Basic to code (YES, I know it's really old. Please don't hate).

Comment: You must show the code(Hint :  `Label1.Text = "Hello"`)

Answer (score 0):

First establish a connection with a database by using sqlcommand,sqldata reader inside a while . Assign the sqldatareader to a varaiable like
Dim r as new sqldatareader
while r.read()
label1,ext=r.getValue(0);
next
Something like that

Comment: Cheers, this gave me a better idea. I will try this and get back to you on it.